# PostgreSQL Accruing values incrementally

Tags: postgresql

I have function in my PostgreSQL database which when called

```
select * from schema.function_name($1,$2,$3);
```

returns a table similar to the following

```
calculation_date | value | increment
2020-01-01       |  1    |  0.5
2020-01-02       |  NULL |  NULL
2020-01-03       |  NULL |  NULL
2020-01-04       |  NULL |  NULL
2020-01-05       |  4    |  2
2020-01-06       |  NULL |  NULL
2020-01-07       |  NULL |  NULL
2020-01-08       |  8.5  |  1
```

As you can see the data returned from this function can be disparate. What I would like to do is query this function so that the `value` column, when `NULL`, increases incrementally based off the most recently populated value in the `increment` column. So in this example, the above table would be transformed into the below

```
calculation_date | value | increment
2020-01-01       |  1    |  0.5
2020-01-02       |  1.5  |  NULL
2020-01-03       |  2.0  |  NULL
2020-01-04       |  2.5  |  NULL
2020-01-05       |  4    |  2
2020-01-06       |  6    |  NULL
2020-01-07       |  8    |  NULL
2020-01-08       |  8.5  |  1
```

If anybody has any suggestions as to how I might go about achieving this output, I'd be grateful. I'm using v10. If any more detail is required, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: The term you're looking for here is "interpolation". [This blog post](https://bytefish.de/blog/postgresql_interpolation/) might get you on track.

Comment: Thanks for the direction @ChrisHeald, that's quite a useful read. I solved the issue in the end by grabbing the last increment value before any null's and multiplying it by the difference in days from that row's date to each subsequent row's date - then adding it on to the previous value. This works in this case as I'm guaranteed a daily time series. Thanks again for the response.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue in the end by grabbing the last increment value before any null's and multiplying it by the difference in days from that row's date to each subsequent row's date - then adding it on to the previous value. This works in this case as I'm guaranteed a daily time series.